# AWS lambda HTTP API only receiving header from POST form

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to send a name and email from a static website to a lambda function through a HTTPS gateway. Here's the JS code that handles the inputs.

```js
    function submitToAPI(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var URL = "https://fvxw67h6bl.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/default/GetData";
            
            let name = (document.getElementById("name") as HTMLInputElement).value;
            let email = (document.getElementById("email") as HTMLInputElement).value;
    
            if (name=="" || email=="")
             {
                 alert("Please Fill All Required Field");
                 return false;
             }
             
            const emailRE = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
             if(!emailRE.test(email)) {
                 alert("Email Address entered, is not valid");
                     return false;
             }
            var data = {
               name : name,
               email : email
             };
     
             var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
             xmlhttp.open("POST", URL);
             xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
             xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(data));
         }
```

I was trying to access the data in the lambda function with:

```js
    name = event["name"]
    email = event["email"]
```

But it kept returning errors.

So I tried printing the event object and this is what it returned.

```json
{
  'version': '2.0',
  'routeKey': 'ANY /GetData',
  'rawPath': '/default/GetData',
  'rawQueryString': '',
  'headers': {
    'accept': '*/*', 
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9', 
    'content-length': '0', 
    'host': 'fvxw67h6bl.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com', 
    'origin': 'http://localhost:3000', 
    'referer': 'http://localhost:3000/', 
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="92", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="92"', 
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0', 
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty', 
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors', 
    'sec-fetch-site': 'cross-site', 
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36', 
    'x-amzn-trace-id': 'Root=1-611f1788-7c27d190689e2be22374fd1f', 
    'x-forwarded-for': '107.2.126.157', 
    'x-forwarded-port': '443', 
    'x-forwarded-proto': 'https'
  },
  'requestContext': {
    'accountId': '551656018604', 
    'apiId': 'fvxw67h6bl', 
    'domainName': 'fvxw67h6bl.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
    'domainPrefix': 'fvxw67h6bl',
    'http': {
      'method': 'POST', 
      'path': '/default/GetData', 
      'protocol': 'HTTP/1.1', 
      'sourceIp': '107.2.126.157', 
      'userAgent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36'
    }, 
    'requestId': 'EWCdaiwUIAMEVOA=', 
    'routeKey': 'ANY /GetData', 
    'stage': 'default', 
    'time': '20/Aug/2021:02:46:32 +0000', 
    'timeEpoch': 1629427592825
  }, 
  'isBase64Encoded': False
}
```

Basically it just returned the header.
How would I access the data I sent through the API?

Comment: Can you check the body of the request that is actually send using the debug tools in your browser, or can you test your endpoint using a CURL request so we can diagnose whether this is a front-end or back-end issue?

Comment: I believe its either backend, or the xmlhttp.send function is causing the issue. Because json.stringify(data) returns {"name":"testname","email":"test@testmail.com"}

Comment: Hence I asked if you can test it for example using a curl request or similar. That would narrow the issue to either the back-end or the front-end.

Comment: Sorry about that, curl -d "{"name":"test", "email":"test@testmail.com"}" https://fvxw67h6bl.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/default/GetData
returns: {"message":"Internal Server Error"}

Comment: If you use the `-d` flag, the content-type header is not set to `application/json`, which might be the reason for the internal server. Can you use `--data-raw` and an `-H 'content-type: application/json'` for the curl? And then have a corresponding server log to ensure the back-end code is the problem?